# How to Set Conditional CSS for a Div with an A Element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set the minimum height of a div if div a exists on the page?

I am trying to align the border of a parent div showing a blog post with tags (i.e. child div a) vs a blog post without any tags (just child div but empty).

I want to set a minimum height of the child div so that the borders remain aligned on desktop irrespective of whether the blog post has a tag or not.

Is there a way to set a condition so that the tag div will get a minimum height but only if the page has a tag div with an a element inside?

For example:

I want to add a minimum height to the below div...

```
<div aria-label="tags for this post" class="post-tags clr"></div>
```

But only if this exists on the page:

```
<div aria-label="tags for this post" class="post-tags clr"><a href="">Tag</a></div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe CSS :has will help (not yet  fully supported in Firefox).

Comment: @AHaworth So how would I go about using :has for the above div? I tried it on Chrome but it didn't work. Perhaps I've coded it incorrectly...

Comment: Can I just check that what you want to do is set the min-height of a div with .post-tags.clr but only if it does not itself have an a element child AND only if there is at least one other div with .post-tags.clr somewhere else on the page which does have an a element?

Comment: If the above is so, I'm afraid I don't think  :has won't work because you cannot nest :has in CSS see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Apologies, I think it can be done without need of nesting the :has provided you know enough to reset the div with the a element's min-height.

Answer (score 1):

On browsers (other than, at the moment, Firefox) you can use the :has in CSS.

This snippet first of all sets the min-height of all the divs with those classes to whatever you want to set the min-height to.

Then it overrides this for the divs which do have an a element child.

Note the need for repeating the body's :has selector in order to make it override the other selector.

```html
<style>
  body:has(div.post-tags.clr a) div.post-tags.clr {
    background: pink;
    min-height: 200px;
  }
  
  body:has(div.post-tags.clr a) div.post-tags.clr:has(a) {
    min-height: initial;
    background: lime;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div aria-label="tags for this post" class="post-tags clr"></div>
  <div aria-label="tags for this post" class="post-tags clr"><a href="">Tag</a></div>
</body>
```